# Getting data only after click in Vuejs

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

Good afternoon everyone. thanks for reading this. I am trying to populate a list of items. objects1 is an array of items with multiple data including an url for getting the item's picture. The issue is that I only see blank instead of the updated picture. When I click "back" (button to go to previous page), I am able to see all the pictures for a second 
before the previous page is shown.

```
 <template>
   <div v-for="item in itemList">
    <div class="item-picture" :style="{ 'backgroundImage' : 'url(' + 
      item.picture + ')' }"></div>
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
      <p>{{item.address}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </template>

<script>
   import axios from 'axios'

   export default {
   name: ‘name1’,
   props: [
      ‘objects1’
   ],
   data () {
     return {
        objects2: [],
     }
   },
   watch: {
    objects1: function () {
      this.objects2 = this.objects1
      for (let i = 0; i < this.objects2.length; i++) {
        this.getPic(this.objects2[i].url, i)
      }
    },
  },
  mounted () {
  },
  updated () {
  },
  methods: {
    getPic (url, index) {
      let _this = this
      axios.get(url)
      .then((res) => {
          _this.objects2[index].picture = res.data.url
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      })
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Vue.set` and see the change detection caveats from the docs  (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Instead of

```
_this.objects2[index].picture = res.data.url
```

Use

```
Vue.set(this.objects2[index], 'picture', res.data.url)
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. It works. I will read that link.